# simplify a flowchart drawn using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Here is a flowchart drawn using tikz. This is lot of code. The positions of some objects are computed by trial and error. How do I simplify it. Also how to make arrows connecting block 4 with the squiggly line straight?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings,snakes}
\tikzset
{ 
process/.style={rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center, text width=2cm, draw},
connector/.style={circle, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=0.5cm, align=center, text width=1cm, draw},
arrow/.style={thick, ->, >=stealth},
database/.style={
      cylinder,
      shape border rotate=90,
      aspect=0.25,
      draw
    }
}  
\tikzset{snake it/.style={decorate, decoration=snake}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (p0){Layers in system xyz};
\node (a) [process, below of=p0, text width=6cm] {Block 1};
\node (b) [process, below of=a, yshift=-1cm, text width=6cm] {Block 2};
\node (c) [process, below of=b, yshift=-1cm, text width=6cm] {Block 3};
\node (d) [process, below of=c, yshift=-1cm, text width=6cm] {Block 4};
\node (e) [process, below of=d, yshift=-3cm, text width=6cm] {Block 5};
\node (f) [process, right of=e, xshift=7cm, text width=6cm] {Block 6};

\path (a.south) -- (a.south east) coordinate[pos=0.5] (a1);
\path (a.south) -- (a.south west) coordinate[pos=0.5] (a2);

\path (b.north) -- (b.north east) coordinate[pos=0.5] (b1);
\path (b.north) -- (b.north west) coordinate[pos=0.5] (b2);
\path (b.south) -- (b.south east) coordinate[pos=0.5] (b3);
\path (b.south) -- (b.south west) coordinate[pos=0.5] (b4);

\path (c.north) -- (c.north east) coordinate[pos=0.5] (c1);
\path (c.north) -- (c.north west) coordinate[pos=0.5] (c2);
\path (c.south) -- (c.south east) coordinate[pos=0.5] (c3);
\path (c.south) -- (c.south west) coordinate[pos=0.5] (c4);

\path (d.north) -- (d.north east) coordinate[pos=0.5] (d1);
\path (d.north) -- (d.north west) coordinate[pos=0.5] (d2);
\path (d.south) -- (d.south east) coordinate[pos=0.5] (d3);
\path (d.south) -- (d.south west) coordinate[pos=0.5] (d4);

\path [draw,snake it]  (-3,-9) -- node[right, xshift=4 cm] { n/w}(3,-9);

\draw[latex-] (a1) -- (b1);
\draw[latex-] (b2) -- (a2);
\draw[latex-] (b3) -- (c1);
\draw[latex-] (c2) -- (b4);
\draw[latex-] (c3) -- (d1);
\draw[latex-] (d2) -- (c4);
\draw[latex-] (1.5,-8.5) --  node[right] {hi} (d3);
\draw[latex-] (d4) -- (-1.5,-8.5);
\draw[latex-] (1.5,-10.5) -- (1.5,-9.5);
\draw[latex-] (-1.5,-9.5) -- (-1.5,-10.5);
\draw [dashed] (e.east) -- (f.west);

\node[database] (db1) at (-2,-13) {DB1};
\node[database] (db2) at (2,-13) {DB2};
\node[database] (db3) at (6,-13) {DB3};
\node[database] (db4) at (10,-13) {DB4};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: How close to the squiggly line do you want the arrows to get?

Comment: I've updated the code to reflect the distances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***This is a response to the original question before the diagram was retroactively expanded by the OP!***

This uses the `chains` library to create the header, snake and, using a single loop, the 4 blocks. The arrows between the main blocks are drawn as part of the same loop. Finally, the arrows to and from the snake are drawn following the same pattern.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=20pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,arrows.meta,decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [start chain=main going below, every on chain/.append style={align=center, text width=60mm, minimum height=10mm}, >={LaTeX[]}]
  \node [on chain] {Layers in system xyz};
  \foreach \i [remember=\i as \iprior] in {1,...,4}
  {
    \node (block \i) [on chain, draw] {Block \i};
    \ifnum\i>1
      \draw [->] (block \iprior.south) +(-15mm,0) coordinate (b\i) -- (block \i.north -| b\i);
      \draw [<-] (block \iprior.south) +(15mm,0) coordinate (k\i) -- (block \i.north -| k\i);
    \fi
  }
  \node (squiggle) [on chain] {};
  \draw [decorate, decoration={snake}] (squiggle.west) -- (squiggle.east);
  \draw [->] (block 4.south -| b4) -- (squiggle -| b4);
  \draw [<-] (block 4.south -| k4) -- (squiggle -| k4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: condensed patterning with chains and loops]

This could be further shortened, but I think it would thereby be significantly less intelligible.

## EDIT

***This is a response to the revised question after the diagram was extensively expanded by the OP.***

Again, this uses the `chains` library together with some loops and a few conditionals. It also uses the `quotes` library to make adding nodes by the arrows easier. It is designed to be extensible so that labels can easily be added to any arrow in the diagram.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=20pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,arrows.meta,decorations.pathmorphing,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [start chain=main going below, every on chain/.append style={align=center, text width=60mm, minimum height=10mm}, >={LaTeX[]}, every edge quotes/.append style={midway, auto, font=\small}, every label/.append style={font=\small}]
  \node [on chain] {Layers in system xyz};
  \foreach \i [remember=\i as \iprior] in {1,...,6}
  {
    \ifnum\i=5
      \node (block s) [on chain, label=right:n/w] {};
      \draw [decorate, decoration={snake}] (block s.west) -- (block s.east);
    \else
      \ifnum\i>5
        \node (block \iprior) [on chain, draw] {Block \iprior};
      \else
        \node (block \i) [on chain, draw] {Block \i};
      \fi
    \fi
  }
  \foreach \i/\j/\k [remember=\i as \iprior (initially 1)] in {2//,3//,4//,s//hi,5//}
  {
    \draw (block \iprior.south) +(-15mm,0) coordinate (b\i) edge ["\j", ->] (block \i.north -| b\i);
    \draw (block \iprior.south) +(15mm,0) coordinate (k\i) edge ["\k", <-] (block \i.north -| k\i);
  }
  \node (block 6) [on chain=going right, draw, join=by {dashed}] {Block 6};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: more chains]

The addition of the beer barrels at the bottom is left as an exercise for the reader.

## EDIT EDIT

Addition of beer barrels:

[image: beer barrels]

## Complete Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=20pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,arrows.meta,decorations.pathmorphing,quotes,shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [start chain=main going below, every on chain/.append style={align=center, text width=60mm, minimum height=10mm}, >={LaTeX[]}, every edge quotes/.append style={midway, auto, font=\small}, every label/.append style={font=\small}, database/.style={cylinder, shape border rotate=90, aspect=0.25, draw}]
  \node [on chain] {Layers in system xyz};
  \foreach \i [remember=\i as \iprior] in {1,...,6}
  {
    \ifnum\i=5
      \node (block s) [on chain, label=right:n/w] {};
      \draw [decorate, decoration={snake}] (block s.west) -- (block s.east);
    \else
      \ifnum\i>5
        \node (block \iprior) [on chain, draw] {Block \iprior};
      \else
        \node (block \i) [on chain, draw] {Block \i};
      \fi
    \fi
  }
  \foreach \i/\j/\k [remember=\i as \iprior (initially 1)] in {2//,3//,4//,s//hi,5//}
  {
    \draw (block \iprior.south) +(-15mm,0) coordinate (b\i) edge ["\j", ->] (block \i.north -| b\i);
    \draw (block \iprior.south) +(15mm,0) coordinate (k\i) edge ["\k", <-] (block \i.north -| k\i);
  }
  \node (block 6) [on chain=going right, draw, join=by {dashed}] {Block 6};
  \path [every node/.style=database] (b5 |- block 5.south) +(0,-10mm) node (db1) {DB1} (k5 |- db1) node {DB2} (block 6.south |- db1) +(-15mm,0) node (db3) {DB3} +(15mm,0) node {DB4};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Explanation

Starting with the options passed to `tikzpicture`:

```
  [start chain=main going below,
```

This creates a chain named `main` which is heading downwards. So each node added will be added below the one before.

```
every on chain/.append style={align=center, text width=60mm, minimum height=10mm},
```

Every node which uses the style `on chain` i.e. every node added to a chain of any sort will have the style attributes given i.e. minimum height of 1cm, text width of 6cm, text aligned to centre.

```
>={LaTeX[]},
```

Every arrow tip will, by default, be of this kind (using the new syntax from the `arrows.meta` library which replaces `arrows`).

```
every edge quotes/.append style={midway, auto, font=\small},
```

The `quotes` library lets you say things like `... edge ["great label"] ...` as a shorthand for `... edge node {great label} ...`. `every edge quotes` sets a style to be applied to all nodes specified in this way.

```
every label/.append style={font=\small},
```

All `label` nodes will use small text.

```
database/.style={cylinder, shape border rotate=90, aspect=0.25, draw}]
```

Style from your code.

```
  \node [on chain] {Layers in system xyz};
```

First node on the chain called `main`.

```
  \foreach \i [remember=\i as \iprior] in {1,...,6}
```

Starts a loop with one variable `\i` which will take the value `1`, then `2`, then ... `6`. After the first loop, the previous value of `\i` will be available as `\iprior`. So, when `\i` is `2`, `\iprior` will be `1`.

```
  {% everything here to be repeated for each \i
    \ifnum\i=5
```

If `\i` is `5`, we want to create the special snake thing rather than a block. We call this `block s`. We add it, as usual to the chain.

```
      \node (block s) [on chain, label=right:n/w] {};
      \draw [decorate, decoration={snake}] (block s.west) -- (block s.east);
    \else
```

If we aren't dealing with the special case, then we distinguish 2 cases: blocks before the snake and blocks after it.

```
      \ifnum\i>5% blocks after the snake i.e. block 5
        \node (block \iprior) [on chain, draw] {Block \iprior};
```

In this case, we want the previous value of `\i`, `\iprior` because our snake stepped the value of `\i` even though we didn't create a regular block.

```
      \else% blocks before the snake i.e. blocks 1-4
        \node (block \i) [on chain, draw] {Block \i};
      \fi
    \fi
  }
```

Completes drawing of blocks 1-5 and the snake.

```
  \foreach \i/\j/\k [remember=\i as \iprior (initially 1)] in {2//,3//,4//,s//hi,5//}
```

Three variables here. Again, the previous value of `\i` is saved as `\iprior`. In the first iteration of the loop, `\iprior` will be equal to `1`. We start `\i` from `2` because we don't want arrows going into and out of the top of block 1.

The syntax `a/b/c` means set `\i` to `a`, `\j` to `b` and `\k` to `c`. `i` here is the number of the block to draw arrows into and out of and `\j` and `\k` are any labels those arrows should take.

```
  {% repeat this set for each triplet of values \i, \j and \k
    \draw (block \iprior.south) +(-15mm,0) coordinate (b\i) edge ["\j", ->] (block \i.north -| b\i);
    \draw (block \iprior.south) +(15mm,0) coordinate (k\i) edge ["\k", <-] (block \i.north -| k\i);
```

This is where the `quotes` stuff is used. It sets `\j` and `\k` as labelling nodes for the arrows drawn. `(a -| b)` means the point which is on the same shelf as `a` (`-`) and above the same point on the ground as `b` (`|`) i.e. `x` coordinate from `b` and `y` coordinate from `a`.

```
  }
```

Complete the loop over the set of triplets.

```
  \node (block 6) [on chain=going right, draw, join=by {dashed}] {Block 6};
```

Add block 6 which means we want the chain to go in a different direction, so instead of `on chain`, we say `on chain=going right`. Here, we tell TikZ to join the block to the previous one using a `dashed` line. (Couldn't use this above because `join` doesn't get you 2 arrows - only 1.)

Finally, add the beer barrels at the bottom. This is using the `|-` syntax explained above.

```
  \path [every node/.style=database] (b5 |- block 5.south) +(0,-10mm)
```

Start at the point with `x` coordinte from `b5` (defined earlier) and `y` from `block5.south` and then come down 10mm.

```
node (db1) {DB1}
```

Make the first database, name it `db1`.

```
 (k5 |- db1) node {DB2}
```

Align the second database with `k5` and the first database.

(block 6.south |- db1) +(-15mm,0) node (db3) {DB3}

We don't have `b6` or `k6` so we need to adjust left and right manually by moving 15mm left to place the third database...

```
+(15mm,0) node {DB4};
```

and 15mm right to place the fourth.

Comment: Thank you. And apologies for not mentioning that I edited the code.

Comment: `The addition of the beer barrels at the bottom is left as an exercise for the reader`. Good one :)

Comment: Your code is concise. But it requires lots of learnings for a beginner to follow.

Comment: @arunmoezhi Couldn't resist adding the beer, after all. You did indicate you wanted less code ;). There are really only 2 key ideas here: one is the use of the `chains` library which basically adds nodes to chains. At any given time, a chain is `going` in a particular direction e.g. `below` or `right` and saying `\node [on chain]...` adds the node onto the chain. It makes it easy to add lots of nodes quickly. The other is the use of loops with `\foreach...`. Basically `\i`, `\j`, `\k` are variables and they loop through the things in the `in {...}`. So you repeat code for each step. What else?

Comment: @arunmoezhi Please see edit. I've tried to break the final code down. Let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another option, not as shorter as [`cfr's answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261857/3954). The main idea here is to take advantage of the `positioning` and `calc` libaries to place the elements. More lopps could've been used, but I decided to sacrify brevity over clarity:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows,positioning,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings,snakes}

\tikzset
{ 
process/.style={rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center, text width=6cm, draw},
connector/.style={circle, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=0.5cm, align=center, text width=1cm, draw},
arr/.style={->, >=latex},
revarr/.style={<-, >=latex},
database/.style={
      cylinder,
      shape border rotate=90,
      aspect=0.25,
      draw
    },
}  
\tikzset{snake it/.style={decorate, decoration=snake}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\Shift{40pt}
\node (p0){Layers in system xyz};
\node (1) [process, below=of p0] {Block 1};
\node (2) [process, below=of 1] {Block 2};
\node (3) [process, below=of 2] {Block 3};
\node (4) [process, below=of 3] {Block 4};
\coordinate[below=1.3cm of 4] (5);
\node (6) [process, below=1.3cm of 5] {Block 5};
\node (7) [process, right=of 6] {Block 6};

\path[draw,snake it]  
  (3.south west|-5) -- (3.south east|-5) node[right] { n/w} ;

\foreach \Valor in {1,...,3}
{
  \draw[arr] 
    ([xshift=-\Shift]\Valor.south) -- ([xshift=-\Shift]\the\numexpr\Valor+1\relax.north);
  \draw[revarr] 
    ([xshift=\Shift]\Valor.south) -- ([xshift=\Shift]\the\numexpr\Valor+1\relax.north);
}

\draw[revarr,shorten >= 0.3cm] 
    ([xshift=-\Shift]4.south) -- ([xshift=-\Shift]5.north);
\draw[revarr,shorten <= 0.3cm] 
    ([xshift=-\Shift]5.south) -- ([xshift=-\Shift]6.north);
\draw[arr,shorten >= 0.3cm] 
    ([xshift=\Shift]4.south) -- ([xshift=\Shift]5.north);
\draw[arr,shorten <= 0.3cm] 
    ([xshift=\Shift]5.south) -- ([xshift=\Shift]6.north);
\draw[dashed]
  (6) -- (7);

\path
  node[database] 
    (db1) at ([yshift=-1cm] $(6.south west)!0.25!(6.south east) $ ) {DB1} 
  node[database] 
    (db2) at ([yshift=-1cm] $(6.south west)!0.75!(6.south east) $ ) {DB2}
  node[database] 
    (db3) at ([yshift=-1cm] $(7.south west)!0.25!(7.south east) $ ) {DB3}
  node[database] 
    (db4) at ([yshift=-1cm] $(7.south west)!0.75!(7.south east) $ ) {DB4};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]